# How to send parameter via ajax in Springmvc that have special characters

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I use `springmvc` and `tinymce` editor. I want to send content of editor as a parameter via ajax. this content may be have special characters. if it have special char content broken. 
1) why the content that have special char don't send completely?`(special char : %,>,<,&)`

```
 <script  type='text/javascript'>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#addStep").click(function(){
 var content = tinyMCE.get("content");
 var dataString = 'content='+ content.getContent();


$.ajax({
type: "post",
url: "addStep.htm",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
```

success: function(response)
     {

```
         if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){ 
            //--------------
         }

    });
    });
```

and my controller

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/addStep.htm",method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public @ResponseBody JsonResponse addStep(@ModelAttribute(value="answer") Answer   answer,BindingResult result,HttpSession session,HttpServletRequest request,ModelMap   model,@ModelAttribute("stepList") List<String> stepList){
    JsonResponse res = new JsonResponse();
    ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(result, "content", "h");
    if(!result.hasErrors()){
        stepList.add(answer);
        res.setStatus("SUCCESS");
        res.setResult(stepList);
    }else{
        res.setStatus("FAIL");
        res.setResult(result.getAllErrors());
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Which error are you getting?

Comment: use `encodeURIComponent(queryString)` instead of `queryString `. But ur url is simple alphabet. Where are the special characters?

Comment: i edited my question. my error is: java.io.charconversionexception ishexdigit

Comment: can you see this site. i help you to use it. my problem is here. go this address www.chetor.org then watch top right then login. user: h and pass:zxcvbn

Comment: You need to relax and think what are you trying to ask.

Comment: ok. that is right. i use a tinymce editor that have content then i want to save this content on db. when in this content be have > or < or % or & content broken and not save in db or save incompletely.why this char(>,<,%,&) not pass over parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be encoded like this

```
var dataString = "content=" + encodeURIComponent(content.getContent());
```